# Netbox Management IP Address

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, netbox

I have installed netbox on an Ubuntu Server.
I have tested the netbox out using this command

> python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --insecure

This works and I have left it running as a task in the background for now.
It's not a permanent solution.

I was able to get the service running, as I am able to access it using

> wget 127.0.0.1:8000

This is a local loopback address and I wanted to know how I can change this to the ip address of the server.
I have tried to change the Server Address in the config but no luck

This is what the systemctl status looks like:

```
Nov 02 12:05:29 l systemd[1]: Started NetBox WSGI Service.
Nov 02 12:05:29 l gunicorn[2330166]: !!!
Nov 02 12:05:29 l gunicorn[2330166]: !!! WARNING: configuration file should have a valid Python extension.
Nov 02 12:05:29 l gunicorn[2330166]: !!!
Nov 02 12:05:29 l gunicorn[2330166]: [2020-11-02 12:05:29 +0000] [2330166] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
Nov 02 12:05:29 l gunicorn[2330166]: [2020-11-02 12:05:29 +0000] [2330166] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2330166)
Nov 02 12:05:29 l gunicorn[2330166]: [2020-11-02 12:05:29 +0000] [2330166] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Nov 02 12:05:29 l gunicorn[2330195]: [2020-11-02 12:05:29 +0000] [2330195] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2330195
```

If someone could point me into the right direction in allowing me to access it from the network using the servers IP Address?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed Gunicorn for wsgi HTTP using pip:

```
pip3 install gunicorn
```

Please follow the official document for systemd service for netbox.

[Reference link](https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/4-gunicorn/)

Use httpd redirect the netbox into apache webserver it will listen the port `0.0.0.0:8085`. You can access netbox with your IP for example your IP is `172.32.32.10` then in browser `172.32.32.10:8085`

Before that Install apache web server `yum install httpd -y`
copy the below config into `/etc/httpd/conf.d/netbox.conf`

```
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
```

Note, the default port for netbox is 8001. It will be redirected to your apache webserver.

**netbox.conf**

```
Listen 8085
ProxyPreserveHost On
ServerName netbox.example.com
Alias /static /opt/netbox/netbox/static
   <Directory /opt/netbox/netbox/static>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
   <Location  /static>
        ProxyPass !
  </Location>

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8001/
```